# 18.04 LTS file access from applications

Tags: 18.04

I have been having difficulty configuring applications in 18.04 to access file systems and mounts. I am not a frequent Ubuntu user although I know Linux in general well.

In this case the application 'vuze-vs' installed from snap will not show any folders or file systems I have created after installation. I have given the folders permission to access using my user, vuze runs as this user as well. The standard `chmod 777`. I can access the folders and mounts from my user via cli. Create and remove files no problem.

When browing in vuze to configure the file destination though these locations are not in the select lists....

Any pointers on what is going on here? If I was using CentOS I would think it is a selinux context type of issue. Or I may be of the mark completely.